# Issue compiling class with method that throws SAXException

Tags: java, xml

I am working on an internship assignment and I am having a problem with an exception.  Im using the DOM method and have thrown the SAX exception anyway in the main, but i keep getting the error

```
CoefficientCalculator.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
   public static void main(String[] args)throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
                                                                              ^
  symbol:   class SAXException
  location: class CoefficientCalculator
1 error
```

When I remove the throwing of the exception I get additional errors.  The remainder of the code is posted below.  Any ideas?

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CoefficientCalculator{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
   {
      double creditScoreAcc = 0;
      double creditSquared;
      double paybackPctAcc = 0;
      double paybackPctSquared;
      double xcrossy;
      double coefficient;
      int itemCount = 0;
      String input1;
      String input2;

      //Create the Document Builders
      DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

      //Build the document
      Document document = builder.parse(new File("SampleData.xml"));

      //Normalize the XML structure
      document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

      //Get and dislplay root node
      Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
      System.out.println(root.getNodeName());

      //Find mean of credit scores
      NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("Funding");

         for(int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++){
            Node node =list.item(i);

               if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                  Element element = (Element) node;
                  input1 = element.getAttribute("creditScore");              
                  double a = Double.parseDouble(input1);
                  input2 = element.getAttribute("totPymtPct");                         
                  double b = Double.parseDouble(input2);

                     if(a > 0){
                        creditScoreAcc += a;
                        paybackPctAcc += b;
                        itemCount++;
                     }

            }  
         }
      creditSquared = Math.pow(creditScoreAcc, 2.0);
      paybackPctSquared = Math.pow(paybackPctAcc, 2.0);
      xcrossy = creditScoreAcc * paybackPctAcc;

      coefficient = CalcCoefficient(creditScoreAcc, paybackPctAcc, xcrossy,
       creditSquared, paybackPctSquared, itemCount);

         }
   //Method to calculate to Correlation Coefficient of two data sets      
   public static double CalcCoefficient(double x, double y, double xy, double x2, double y2, int n){
      double c = (n)*(xy)-(x * y)/Math.sqrt(n*x2-(Math.pow(x, 2.0)))*Math.sqrt(n*y2-(Math.pow(y, 2.0)));
      return c;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not Import `org.xml.sax.SAXException`. Add it to your code and try again.